# Sending floats w/NRF8001

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using Blend Micro (basically Arduino Uno + Nordic nRF8001) to gather and send sensor data via BLE. Can't figure out how to send floats.

Here's a snip of code:

```
if ((lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT_TX)) && (lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_TX)) && (lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_CARBON_MONOXIDE_LEVEL_TX)))
  {

    // Read DHT & MQ7 sensors
    h = dht.readHumidity(); // Read humidity from DHT
    t = dht.readTemperature(); // Read temperature as Celsius from DHT
    f = dht.readTemperature(true); // Read temperature as Fahrenheit from DHT
    int VoutAn = analogRead(MQ7PIN); //Read Vout in analog from MQ7

    // Compute heat index
    hi = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);

    // Compute CO in PPM
    float Vout = (5.0/1023)*VoutAn;
    co = 100.468*(pow(((5/Vout)-1),-1.43));

    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT_TX, &f, sizeof(f));
    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_TX, &h, sizeof(h));
    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_CARBON_MONOXIDE_LEVEL_TX, &co, sizeof(co));
  }
```

And here's the compile error:

> Arduino: 1.0.6 (Mac OS X), Board: "Blend Micro 3.3V/16MHz (overclock)"
>
> BLE-DHT-MQ7-Test.ino: In function 'void loop()':
>
> BLE-DHT-MQ7-Test.ino:287: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'uint8_t*'
>   for argument '2' to 'bool lib_aci_send_data(uint8_t, uint8_t*,
>   uint8_t)'
>
> BLE-DHT-MQ7-Test.ino:288: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'uint8_t*'
>   for argument '2' to 'bool lib_aci_send_data(uint8_t, uint8_t*,
>   uint8_t)'
>
> BLE-DHT-MQ7-Test.ino:289: error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'uint8_t*'
>   for argument '2' to 'bool lib_aci_send_data(uint8_t, uint8_t*,
>   uint8_t)'

My understanding of the aci_send_data function is that argument 2 is a uint8_t variable that points to the data in memory to be sent, and that this data can be in any form. But it only seems to work if the data is in a uint8_t variable - e.g. this compiles if I convert my variables to uint8_t - but I need floats...

So my questions:

Am I understanding the aci_send_data function correctly?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

If not, how can I send floats?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the parameters needed by `lib_aci_send_data` function however, according to [this code](https://github.com/RedBearLab/BLEShield/blob/master/Arduino/libraries/RBL_BLEShield/ble_shield.cpp) it seems that the first parameter accepts the TX pin, the second one is the reference of the first byte (in a byte array) to be interpreted as a number, and the third is the length or number of bytes to consider.

The data type `float` is a 4-byte variable. If we have an array of bytes representing the float number, we can pass the reference of the first byte in the second parameter of the function, and pass `4` as the length (or number of bytes to consider) in the third parameter.

To convert float to byte array, see this [thread](http://developer.mbed.org/forum/helloworld/topic/2053/?page=1#comment-10382). In your case, it would look like this:

```
typedef union _data {
  float f;
  char s[4];//since f takes 4 bytes
} myData;

myData q;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  q.f = 1.234;
  //you can access the char array by using q.s
  //q.s[0]  q.s[1] ...
  //take note that q.s is a reference to the first element
  //so we can pass that immediately to the 2nd parameter
}
```

Now you can use the function in this way: `lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_TX, q.s, 4);`

I cannot test this as of now since I'm on a different machine, please let me know if this was successful, I'm willing to add edits if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works! Seems a little cumbersome, but here's the code for getting all 3 variables I need to send as floats:

```
if ((lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT_TX)) && (lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_TX)) && (lib_aci_is_pipe_available(&aci_state, PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_CARBON_MONOXIDE_LEVEL_TX)))
  {

    typedef union _dataF
    {
      float f;
      uint8_t fInt[4];
    } myDataF;

    myDataF F;

    typedef union _dataH
    {
      float h;
      uint8_t hInt[4];
    } myDataH;

    myDataH H;

    typedef union _dataCO
    {
      float co;
      uint8_t coInt[4];
    } myDataCO;

    myDataCO CO;

    // Read DHT & MQ7 sensors
    h = dht.readHumidity(); // Read humidity from DHT
    t = dht.readTemperature(); // Read temperature as Celsius from DHT
    f = dht.readTemperature(true); // Read temperature as Fahrenheit from DHT
    int VoutAn = analogRead(MQ7PIN); //Read Vout in analog from MQ7

    // Compute heat index
    hi = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);

    // Compute CO in PPM
    float Vout = (5.0/1023)*VoutAn;
    co = 100.468*(pow(((5/Vout)-1),-1.43));

    F.f = f;
    H.h = h;
    CO.co = co;

    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_TEMPERATURE_MEASUREMENT_TX, F.fInt, 4);
    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_TX, H.hInt, 4);
    lib_aci_send_data(PIPE_AIR_QUALITY_SENSOR_CARBON_MONOXIDE_LEVEL_TX, CO.coInt, 4);
  }
```

I put the sensor data into wider scope floats as I draw on them elsewhere in the program.